# Output text C++

Tags: c++, output

How may I add a none fixed text to a `.txt` file? So that I can add text that I just added by hand to the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
 int x;

  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("teksts.txt", ios::app);
  myfile << x;
  myfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Also after the file has added the text to the `.txt` document, how can I pause the run window so It would say "**The file has been updated!**" and only after I press enter it would exit?

Comment: You cannot write a variable to a file, and then replace it later, just like you can't write a variable to cout, and then replace it later.

Comment: Is there any other way I can do this with out variable? Been looking at tutorials all day, but its not working so far, everything is with numbers or fixed text output.

Comment: That's how it works. I just put a couple options in an answer, but you may have to parse your file in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give x a value before you send it to the file ( currently you are just sending junk value)

```
  myfile.open ("teksts.txt", ios::app);
  cout << "Please enter text to write to file: ";
  cin >> x;
  myfile << x;
```

Just add a statement like cout<< "The file has been updated!";.

To view the output use getchar();

If you want to overwrite the contents each time you open the file, open it in ios::out mode instead. Currently you are using ios::app.

I would also advise to change x into a string, that way you will be able to save text to it.

Comment: How can I add a value that i can change every time I open the program? So it would not just save the same text/value to the .txt file?

Comment: @DoriaLatro What do you want to write? User input? (that's what this answer does) or a random number or something?

Comment: I think file needs to be opened in overwrite mode. Thats what "everytime new" means.

Comment: I want add text when starting the program.

       Like:
Open program >
Asks to enter a text : >
Enter "text" >
Text gets saved to the .txt file. >
say "The file has been updated!" And after I press ender it exit. > End. 

In the .txt file it should have added the new "text" I just added, with out replacing the old one.

Comment: Now you made it clear. Then append mode will work fine.

Comment: append mode? Sorry I really dont know what that is.

Comment: ios::app , thats append mode. If you want to overwrite onto your text file use ios::out, else if you want to add more data to the existing file use ios::app mode. In your program,you have used ios app mode                           myfile.open ("teksts.txt", ios::app);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a variable to a file, and then replace it later, just like you can't write a variable to cout, and then replace it later.

If you're looking to open a file, write something to it, and then reopen it later, you'll need to use a unique string of text, and then replace that.

```
myfile << "ABC %%UNIQUE_STRING%% DEF";
```

Then later...

```
string uniqueValue = "%%UNIQUE_STRING%%";
string stringObject;
getline(myfile, stringObject);
stringObject.replace(stringObject.find(uniqueValue), uniqueValue.length(), "New Value");
```

If you're looking for something automatic, everytime the program runs, (since the above will only work once), you'll have to be more clever. One potential option would be to always write to the same character index, and the same amount of characters.